# iPhone - Issues accessing viewController variables from my delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Hi everybody that's my first post here, so i'll try to be as clear as possible.

So, in my project, I need to get an xml document from a webService, with SOAP, and then parse it in a NSMutableArray (This is done). Then I would like to display my table's content in a tableview. Problem is, in my delegate I can't access anything of my viewController.

I have 3 classes, SOAP_TestViewController, SOAP_TestAppDelegate and XMLParser. I'm sending the array containing the parsed file from XMLParser to the Appdelegate, and then I would like to update an array in my viewController to use it in order to update my tableview.

Here's a bit of code, may help to understand.

```
#import "SOAP_TestAppDelegate.h"
#import "SOAP_TestViewController.h"
#import "XMLParser.h"

@implementation SOAP_TestAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {        

[window addSubview:viewController.view];

NSLog(@"%@", viewController.donnees);  //Here I can get what I want.

[window makeKeyAndVisible]; 

}

-(void)afficher{

NSLog(@"%@", viewController.donnees);  //But there, it returns (null)...

[viewController reload];

}


- (void)dealloc {

[viewController release];

[window release];

[super dealloc];

}

@end
```

I spent like hours to find a solution. AND, I noticed something. Like the comments say in my code, I can access what I want in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` function, but not outside. So am I working on copies or something when i'm out of this function ? And what should I do to access my "donnees" table ?

I'm such a beginner in cocoa coding so please tell me if i'm doing things wrong.

(Please be indulgent with my English :-) I'm not bilingual yet ^^')

EDIT

My  `afficher`  function looked like this at the beginning. I call it from XMLParser with the parsed array as parameter. I was sur it would work but...

```
-(void) afficher:(NSMutableArray *)array
{
    NSLog(@"%@", array);  //returns the array sent by XMLParser.
    [viewController.donnees addObjectsFormArray:array];
    NSLog(@"%@", viewController.donnees);  //returns null.
}
```

That's weird, it's like donnees wasn't even allocated and initialized...

Comment: whe are you calling `afficher`? also, note that the syntax is incorrect, `:` introduces a parameter and you have none...

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I just modified this function, consider there are no `:`. I call `afficher` in `parserDidEndDocument` in my XMLParser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your *viewController* is not nil? Ok, that's unlikely. Then are you sure your *donnees* array is not nil AND it is NSMutableArray, but not NSArray?

And, btw, you CAN access the properties out of appDelegate from anywhere. I'm not fond of this solution, but just to make a clarification on that. In any class you can do smth like:

```
#include "YourAppDelegate.h"

- (void)someMethod {
    YourAppDelegate *yourDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    yourDelegate.donnees = self.anotherArray;
}
```

Of course, *donnees* should be a property in this case. Cheers!

Comment: Yes donnees is definitely an NSMutableArray, and I put a string in when the application launches. I can then get it in `applicationDidFinishLoading` but nowhere else... I tested and effectively, my viewController is null outside `applicationDidFinishLoading`, but it's not released anywhere (except the dealloc). Any idea ?

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to access the same object from everywhere? :) How *viewController* is defined in your XMLParser?

Comment: I think I need to clarify some things. I'm not trying to acces viewController from XMLParser ! From XMLParser I send my array (with parsed file) to my delegate and then I try to assing it to donnes (wich is one of my viewController properties) from my delegate. So I access it only from the delegate. So I really don't understand what's happenning :(

Comment: I was instanciating my delegate in my XMLParser class instead of using the declaration in your very first answer. Thanks that worked like that ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting a breakpoint that will stop the program any time the `viewController` ivar is changed; to do this:

1. set a breakpoint in your appDelegate, then debug the program;
2. when the program stops in your appDelegate, execute this command in the gdb console:

   ```
     (gdb) watch -location self->viewController
   ```
3. continue debugging.

Now, each time that `viewController` is set a value, the program will stop, so you can inspect who is trying to set it to nil and why.

OLD:

The problem lies possibly with the step you describe as "I'm sending the array containing the parsed file from XMLParser to the Appdelegate".

Indeed, it seems that when your app starts, i.e., before the parsing, `viewController.donnees` is defined; after the parsing, it is null. You are obviously doing something wrong in between.

It could be the `parserDidEndDocument` method that tries to set the `donnees` ivar in the wrong way. Without more code it is not possible to help further, but I hope that this hint could guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Makaron helped me to fix the problem, in fact it came from my XMLParser.m. Here I was instanciating the delegate instead of using myDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];... Dumb mistake I have to say ^^'

Answer (score -1):

refer this:

```
-(void) rar:(NSMutableArray *)array
{
    NSLog(@"%@", array);  //returns the array sent by XMLParser.
    [viewController.donnees addObjectsFormArray:array];
    NSLog(@"%@", viewController.donnees);  //returns null.
}
```